# CSS problem with IE6 to render a menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, menu

I'm not a designer, so my knowledge of CSS/Javascript is a bit limited. Unfortunately I received a task to solve an issue with a menu (rendered with div, ul and li elements and CSS/jQuery).

The menu renders fine in all browsers except IE6. But I have no idea on how to fix the problem at hand.

The problem occurs in the following [page](http://azl.mediasurface.nl/werknemer/mijnsituatieverandert/) (again, only in IE6).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you remove the CSS does the menu render OK?

Comment: The menu is rendered correctly, just the positioning of the elements is incorrect in IE 6. And this part is completely dependent on the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this (to your IE6-only stylesheet, of course):

```
.subMenu { zoom: 1 }
```

That gives submenus "layout" and makes it work for me, though it's a bit hard to test with the menu being dynamic.

If something isn't working correctly in IE6, there's a good chance [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) is the culprit.

#### Edit:

To fix the border problem, you can add `vertical-align: top` (other values may work as well) to the menu (the `<ul>`). I can't remember exactly what it is anymore, but IE6 has some issues with margins etc. and list items.

Comment: Thanks, this almost solved the problem. Now I need to figure out the difference of the borders between the Firefox and IE6 versions. In IE6 the top border is not yet correctly displayed.